# Equations of motion: Calculate location of point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, computational-physics, algorithms

The scenario is that a user is dragging an object on a touchscreen. I want to calculate the position of the object as the finger drags it across the screen. I also want to account for any acceleration from the finger speed and decelerate the object when the user lets go of the object.

Similar to this, here the object is the entire grid of apps.

[image: apple watch view]

At irregular but frequent intervals I am given a touch event. A touch event consists of two pieces of information $x$ and $t$.

Where $x$ is the position of the finger in pixels and $t$ is the timestamp in milliseconds.

(I am also given $y$ but let's ignore that for now).

For example

```
 x  |  t
157 | 684
164 | 685
171 | 695
177 | 702
182 | 710
189 | 721
196 | 727
202 | 739
208 | 745
214 | 755
221 | 762
235 | 779
242 | 790
250 | 796
258 | 805
266 | 815
274 | 822
283 | 832
291 | 840
301 | 848
318 | 868
```

On the first event, the object is stationary so I use this event as the initial reference position and velocity is $0$.

For all subsequent events I calculate the new object position as follows

$$x_o' = x_f' - x_f + x_o $$

$x_o'$ is the object's new position

$x_o$ is the object's previous position

$x_f'$ is the finger's current position

$x_f$ is the finger's previous position

The above works well to some extent. It updates the object linearly to the position of the finger but it does not account for acceleration, momentum or friction when the user lets go.

I can calculate the acceleration at any point using

$$a = \frac{v - u}{t}$$

Where $v$ is

$$v = \frac{x_f' - x_f}{t}$$

and $u$ is previous speed.

How can I use this acceleration to calculate the new position? And how do I account for friction and deceleration?

I vaguely remember [SUVAT equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion#SUVAT_equations) from 10 years ago and I'm having a pleasant renaissance of my adolescent inner physicist but I haven't got the solution yet.

I would gladly take hints if you feel I'm close to the answer.

Comment: I think there's a problematic use of syntax in $$x_o = x_f - x_f' + x_o $$ I think you should distinguish the next object position with a prime or some dummy subscript as it is presently confusing. Maybe  $$x'_o = x_f - x_f' + x_o $$

Comment: Sure, done. Feel free to edit.

Comment: I don't think I understand. If your system can tell where you are touching the screen, then why don't you just track where the finger is touching the screen. i.e. set $x_o=x_f$ at all points in time. This is usually how you do "drag and drop" events.

Comment: Because that will only move it to where you land - I am trying to have a kind of throwing effect like when you scroll on a page

Comment: Right, so you can have it follow the finger, and then when released you can have it slide to a stop based on the position and velocity when released. I don't understand why you need to have a more complicated tracking mechanism while the finger is on. Also, make sure you tag me in your comment so I get notified.

Answer (score 1):

Depending how you want your object on the screen to respond to the finger there are many ways to go about it. But at the core it will always be the following set of equations:
$$x(t+\Delta t)=x(t)+v(t)\Delta t+\frac{1}{2}a(t)\Delta t^2$$
$$v(t+\Delta t) =v(t)+a(t)\Delta t$$
$$a(t)=\kappa a_{f}(t)$$
provided that $\Delta t$ is small enough. Where $x,v,a$ are the quantities related to the object and $a_f$ is the acceleration of the finger as calculated by the touch data and $\kappa$ is how strongly you want to couple the response of the object to the finger movement.

The above equations let you calculate the next position of the object, provided we know the starting values $x(0)$ and $v(0)$ which you can using the touch data.

Now if you want to add friction to the picture, you can modify the acceleration to have a velocity dependence as follows:
$$a(t)=\kappa a_f(t)-bv(t)^2$$
where $b$ is related to how much damping you need in your system.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to run a simulation after the user is done dragging. The **real** problem us getting the initial conditions of the simulation at the moment of release.

Find the release position is easy (take the last point), but finding the release velocity is a bit more complex. You can just take an finite difference of the last two points, or average several points together. With the data provided the finite difference velocity $v_i = (x_i-x_{i-1})/(t_i-t_{i-1})$ is *very noisy*.

[image: fig1]

You can somewhat smooth things by averaging two points

[image: fig2]

You see the final velocity changed from `0.85` to `0.35`.

A better approach might be to fit a polynomial of 2nd order to the data. Find a library that can do that or [roll your own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8005339/380384) and then estimate velocity from the fit coefficients $C_1$ and $C_2$ as seen below:

[image: fig3]

[image: fig4]

The final velocity is `1.018` in this case.

Now take you release conditions `x_n` and `v_n` and run a simulation, with some kind of rule for the acceleration. Like `a=-(const)` or `a=-d*v` for damping or whatever physics you want to emulate.

```
h = (time step)
t = t_n
x = x_n
v = v_n
do
  a = acceleration(t,x,v)
  t = t + h
  x = x + h * v
  v = v + h * a
while abs(v) > tolerance
```

this loop will run until the speed is less than a tolerance value. Make sure that the solution does not blow up (speed always increasing), unless that is desired and you want a different termination condition.